# PSQL базу создать через терминал

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql

Успешно работает

```
sudo su - postgres -c "createuser adminDb"
sudo su - postgres -c "createdb testDb"
```

Как дать права роли на базу данных через sudo, не заходя на программу?

```
grant all privileges on database testDb to adminDb;
```

И задать пароль созданному пользователю? Прошу помочь

Comment: [createuser](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createuser.html) и [createdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev можно по подробнее, что бы и сразу и пароль задать

Comment: По ссылкам всё есть.

Comment: `sudo su` — это, блин, прекрасно :). Как только не извернутся люди, лишь бы пароль не вводить.